# Where to set up Workspaces & 10.04 Look & Feel?

Tags: installation, 13.04, workspaces, appearance, taskbar

Unable to find setup for multiple workspaces.

Previous response to another question gives:

"System Settings > Appearance > Behavior Tab > Enable Workspaces"

but "Appearance" is not even offered as an options.

Also want old 10.04 menu & task bar look & feel.  This new default is way overboard for "hide the system".

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about 10.04 (as in the title), or about 13.04 (as in the tags)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the Software Center and search for Appearance

[image]

This will install the Appearance icon you are looking for.

As far as look and feel of 10.04... I haven't got a clue!